# T-SQL: insert variable inside declared URL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, ssms, declare

I have an easy problem that I cannot solve.

If you visit this URL with your browser:

[http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name="Auckland"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name=%22Auckland%22]-%3E.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;)

OSM returns for you all the cinemas in Auckland in JSON.

I would like to dynamically query that through T-SQL but first of all I need to find out how to insert the variable of the city name inside the URL:

```
DECLARE @place as NVARCHAR(30) SET @place = 'Auckland'

DECLARE @URL as VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @URL = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name="' + @place +'"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;';
```

This declaration doesn't work and SSMS phosphatize it in red:

[image]

Not sure how to come out from this problem.

I followed multiple guides but they all say to use `' + @variable + '` but in my case is not working.

Why?

Comment: Your code runs for me.  Note that SSMS highlights string literals in red.  This is just how that IDE behaves; it doesn't mean there is any problem.

Comment: No problem with code, just editor has a problem with coloring

Comment: please, post the reply and I will mark it as correct. Siriously? Is the first time I see SSMS having problems with the IDE. I don't understand why? If you know why please post it. I'm sure I'm not the only one that wasted time for this. Thank you

Comment: Actually SSMS mark web url in blue color.

Comment: Don't forget to escape apostrophes and such (for the URL, not for the SQL syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a syntaxic coloration of editor. You can config him into you IDE.

Note you can do it too:

```
DECLARE @place as VARCHAR(30) = 'Auckland'

DECLARE @URL as VARCHAR(MAX)=FORMATMESSAGE('http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name="%s"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;',@place) ;
```